# VS Code: Go - main redeclared in this block

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

This warning/problem pops up in VS code;

main redeclared in this block compiler(DuplicateDecl)
<*my another Go file name in my directory*> other declaration of main

I am have all my Go practice files in one directory and each file has a func main() block.

Is anyone familiar with the warning? if so how may I resolve.

But, Even though I get this error.. or what ever you call it..

I can still run my Go code in the terminal and see my input/output without any error.

Comment: "I am have all my Go practice files in one directory and each file has a func main() block." -- This is your problem. This is not allowed. You can only have one `func main()` per package. And each package must be in its own directory.

Comment: Despite being closed, this Q&A solves my problem.  Therefore IMO it should definitely *not* be deleted, on top of being closed.

Answer (score 22):

Separating them into their own directories is the only solution.

In Go, a directory is a package, and a package can only have one function with a given name (with the exception of `init()`, which is a special case). You think of all your `.go` files in a directory as separate, but Go does not; it sees a single package, and that package declares multiple functions called `main`, which is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, I resolved this problem by creating a directory for each Go file.

I know it is not a perfect solution for this problem..

If some one knows some thing please share with us.

Comment: "I know it is not a perfect solution for this problem." -- No, this is the perfect solution. In fact, it's the only solution.